# got Load report failed on crystal-report and winform program

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

i have C# WinForm program that run sql-server query and fill crystal-report.

when i have a little data resault from the query - its works excellent.

but when i have a big data resault from the query - i got this error:

**Load report failed**

my code for fill the dataset:

```
SQL = "select * from MyTable";
dsPrint = new DataSet();
dsPrint = dbSQL.fill_Dataset(SQL, "Table");
```

my code for open the crystal-report form:

```
Form PI = new frmPrint();
PI.ShowDialog();
PI.Close();
PI.Dispose();
GC.Collect();
```

in my form that hold the crystal-report code (on form Activated):

```
PP = new CryREP();
PP.SetDataSource(dsPrint);
PP.PrintOptions.PrinterName = MyParam.Printer;
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = PP;
crystalReportViewer1.Zoom(100); 
PP.Refresh();
```

and on form FormClosing:

```
PP.Dispose();
crystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
PP.Clone();
GC.Collect();
```

I tried everything, I've been discouraged ):

**EDIT:**

this is the full error log

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80000000): The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached.
   ב-  CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   ב-  CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options)
   ב-  CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
```

EDIT2:

also i try this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOftware/Crystal Decisions/Report Application Server/InprocServer/ReportDocument

Change the value of the field MaxNumOfRecords to -1(For Unlimited No. of records)
```

but still - same error.....

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full text form the exception

Comment: on the try and catch when i try to open the crystal-report form - i only got this error: Load report failed

Comment: Is there an InnerException?

Comment: i update the question